# display an array in gdb with stride in C

Tags: arrays, c, gdb

In fortran for an array defined with

```
integer, allocatable :: m(:)
m = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

If I want only even terms, I can do

```
(gdb) p m
$2 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 4)
(gdb) p m(::2)
$3 = (1, 3, 4)
```

I want to do the same in C witth a "builtin command" . I tried some cast

```
(gdb) p t

$2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}
(gdb) p *((int (*)[3][2])&t)
$3 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 7}}
```

but it does not work. I want to try to avoid a solution using a macro like in

```
(gdb) define print_even
Type commands for definition of "print_even".
End with a line saying just "end".
>set $i = 0
>while $i < sizeof($arg0) / sizeof(int)
 > print $arg0[$i]
 > set $i = $i + 2
 >end
>end
(gdb) print_even t
$4 = 1
$5 = 3
$6 = 4
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  Besides macros you could also use Guile or Python to write suitable functionality.  You could generate the file with gdb commands and `load` it.  Another option is to implement a feature in your program to generate the data you want then call that function from gdb.

Comment: For this kind of stuff I use [duel](https://github.com/vuvova/gdb-tools), and the command for your example would look like `dl t[(..3)*2]`.

Comment: duel seems to be very powerful. I will have a look at it. Thanks

Comment: With duel, effectively I can use commands like `dl t[(0..10)=>if(_ % 2 == 0) _]` to display only even terms

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there is dirty hack. I can force the language to be fortran when it is c, such has

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at cono.c:5
5         t[0]++;
(gdb) p t
$1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}
(gdb) set language fortran
Warning: the current language does not match this frame.
(gdb) p t(:5:2)
$2 = (1, 3, 5)
(gdb) whatis t
type = int (0:5)
(gdb) set language c
(gdb) whatis t
type = int [6]
(gdb)
```